# Need help converting a SQL left join query into LINQ format

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

i'm new to LINQ and not very good with the syntax yet. Could someone help me convert this SQL query into a LINQ statement for use inside my C# project.

```
SELECT g.GalleryTitle, m.*
FROM Media AS m LEFT JOIN Galleries AS g ON m.GalleryID = g.GalleryID
WHERE m.MediaDate >= GETDATE() - 30
ORDER BY m.Views DESC
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You must show your entity objects model for concrete query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from m in Db.Media
join g in Db.Galleries on m.GalleryID equals g.GalleryID into MediaGalleries
from mg in MediaGalleries.DefaultIfEmpty()
where m.MediaDate >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30)
orderby m.Views descending
select new
{
    GalleryTitle = mg != null ? mg.GalleryTitle : null,
    Media = m
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test it right now, but it should be something like this:

```
var result = Media.GroupJoin(Galleries, m => m.GalleryID, g => g.GalleryID, 
                    (m, g) => new {m, g})
                  .SelectMany(mg => mg.g.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
                    (m,g) => new { Media = m.m, GalleryTitle = g != null ? g.GalleryTitle : default(string) })
                  .OrderByDescending(m => m.Media.Views).ToList();
```

Comment: Hope it's fine now. Thanks for noticing that. It's a pain to write left joins using lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from m in Media

             join g in Galleries
               on m.GalleryId equals g.GalleryId
             into gJoinData
             from gJoinRecord in gJoinData.DefaultIfEmpty( )

             where m.MediaDate.CompareTo( DateTime.Today.AddDays( -30.0 ) ) >= 0
             orderby m.Views descending

             select new
             {
                 M_Record = m,
                 GalleryTitle = gJoinRecord.GalleryTitle
             };
```